# Why myr code crash on Spyder but compile on PyCharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, spyder

I work with `keras` on PyCharm. Warnings are raised but I can still download keras.

```
C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.JPIJNSWNNAN3CE6LLI5FWSPHUT2VXMTH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
[0.00057089 0.00057107 0.00057089 ... 0.00055955 0.00055907 0.00055975]
2021-02-20 13:15:50.259667: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:50.260635: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-02-20 13:15:56.593305: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-20 13:15:56.603918: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-02-20 13:15:57.020189: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.2415GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 14.92GiB/s
2021-02-20 13:15:57.022954: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.024729: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.026541: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.028396: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.030143: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.031909: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.034313: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.036670: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:15:57.036909: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-20 13:15:57.043732: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-20 13:15:57.045880: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-20 13:15:57.046176: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      
2021-02-20 13:15:57.046345: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-20 13:15:57.261012: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

When I try the same program with the same env on Spyder, I can't use `keras`.

```
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`


2021-02-20 13:21:37.133088: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:21:37.133212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-02-20 13:22:47.013563: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-20 13:22:47.013642: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I use the same `site-packages`, I tried to disable warning with

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("keras").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

But it still crash.

Comment: The two IDES obviously run on different virtual environments or default python executables.

Comment: Pycharm might have Tensorflow installed already. Spyder IDE expecting Tensorflow to be installed. Install Tensorflow in Spyder usning `pip install tensorflow'. Thanks!

Comment: Keras library requires Tensorflow as backend framework.